# How do I filter out random sample from dataframe in which there are different sample size for each value, in python?

Tags: python, pandas, random, sample

I have to filter out random sample from Data on which:

'a' should have 6 values,

'b' should have 4 values and

'c' should have 7 values randomly.

```
Data    Value

a       1
a       2
a       3
a       4
a       5
a       6
a       7
a       8
a       9
a       10
b       1
b       2
b       3
b       4
b       5
b       6
b       7
b       8
b       9
c       1
c       2
c       3
c       4
c       5
c       6
c       7
c       8
```

I want output as:

```
Data Value

a     3
a     5
a     7    
a     2
a     4
a     9
b     3
b     5
b     7
b     8
c     1
c     3    
c     4    
c     5
c     6
c     7
c     9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define counts of samples for each group and then `groupby` with `sample`:

```
d = {'a':6, 'b':4, 'c':7}

df = df.groupby('Data', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(d[x.name]))
print (df)
   Data  Value
7     a      8
5     a      6
0     a      1
2     a      3
9     a     10
8     a      9
17    b      8
18    b      9
15    b      6
14    b      5
22    c      4
23    c      5
25    c      7
21    c      3
20    c      2
24    c      6
19    c      1
```

Another aproach with filtering only values of matched of keys of dict:

```
d = {'a':6, 'b':4, 'c':7}

df = pd.concat([df[df['Data'].eq(k)].sample(v) for k, v in d.items()], ignore_index=True)
```